# C#/XAML for HTML5 conversion tool for Silverlight project to HTML5

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I wanted to convert Silverlight project to HTML5 using CSHTML5 tool

http://www.cshtml5.com/download.aspx.

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 version with me.

Need guidance to convert project using combination of these tools.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a step-by-step tutorial here:
http://www.cshtml5.com/links/migrating-from-silverlight.aspx

> 1. You start by creating a new empty "CSHTML5 Project",
> 2. You then copy all your C#/XAML files from your Silverlight/WPF project into the new CSHTML5 project,
>      *UPDATE: a "Silverlight Migration Wizard" is now available to help you create the projects and copy the files. It can be launched from the Tools menu of Visual Studio:*
>      [image]
>      The migration wizard can be launched from the Tools menu of Visual Studio.
> 3. You then patch the code until it compiles and runs fine,
> 4. And then, every time you build the CSHTML5 project, the compiler generates the final cross-platform HTML and JavaScript files. Those files are auto-generated, so you are not expected to modify them manually (read the section below titled "[You keep coding in C#/XAML](http://www.cshtml5.com/links/migrating-from-silverlight.aspx#keep-coding-in-csharp-xaml)"). Furthermore, the produced files are self-contained - meaning that they have no dependencies - which means that they can be redistributed very easily, or deployed to any server (read the section below about [deployment](http://www.cshtml5.com/links/migrating-from-silverlight.aspx#deployment)).